# Make a request every 100 ms with setInterval, but the request can sometimes take more than 100 ms

Tags: javascript, python, video-streaming, setinterval

I need to update an image in a `<canvas>` 10 times per second, with data coming from an HTTP request:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    i += 1;
    console.log("sending request", i);
    fetch("/data")   // this can sometimes take more than 100 ms
        .then((r) => r.arrayBuffer())
        .then((arr) => {
            // update canvas with putImageData...
            console.log("finished processing", i);
        });

}, 100);
```

It works, but since the request sometimes takes more than 100ms, it gives results like:

```
sending request 1
sending request 2
sending request 3
finished processing 3
sending request 4
sending request 5
finished processing 5
sending request 6
sending request 7
sending request 8
```

Question:

**Are the "not-finished-to-process" requests queued for later (then it will make everything even slower!), or are they just dropped?** By the way, how can I modify my example in order to test if it's the former or the latter (I haven't been able to to a MCVE confirming the former or latter)?

Since it's video, I need to drop frames if the server takes too long to respond, how would you do it?

PS: example Python server code that takes 150 ms to respond:

```
import bottle, time
app = bottle.Bottle()
@bottle.route('/')
def index():
    return open("test.html", "r").read()
@bottle.route('/data')
def data():
    time.sleep(0.150)
    return b"0000"
bottle.run(port=80)
```

Comment: `fetch` supports the `AbortController` interface, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController

Comment: Also `finished processing 3`  you might find it's actually just `finished processing 1`, you want to create a closure on `i` to get better logging here.

Comment: @Keith oh yes right, how to do a closure here? In this general context, would you still use `setInterval`, or recursive `setTimeout`, or another method to drop the frames?

Comment: For the closure just do `let i2 = i;` inside your `setInterval` and console log that instead.  The `var` is global,  where the `let i2 = i` will be closure on the `fetch`.  Personally I would use a recursive `setTimeout`, and wouldn't even use the `AbortController` here, because if something is taking a long time, executing again won't speed it up from the same server.   If you want 200 ms frame time,   1. grab current time, 2. execute fetch, 3. calculate difference from start time, subtract from 200, and wait that amount, if negative time, just do fetch straight away.

Comment: The above assumes the next frame will take the same time to fetch as the last,  so this won't be exactly 200 ms,  without client side buffering that would be impossible.   But is should be pretty close, and the nice thing is that if the network speed goes up / down, this will adjust accordingly,  so some frames might take 300ms if network is bad, but should then go back to 200 ms if network is good, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your output is currently wrong, therefore I would extract the code in a `function`, so that you always know which `i` you are currently in.

Take a look at the [async keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in JavaScript. This helps you to wait for a promise to resolve before making another request. (If you don't want to wait just remove the `await` in the `setInterval`). The `sendRequest` function will always resolve after 100ms.

```js
var i = 0;
setInterval(async () => {
    i += 1;
    console.log("sending request", i);
    await sendRequest(i) // you may want to remove await here
}, 100);

async function sendRequest(i) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100); // resolves the promise if the api takes longer than 100ms

    const data = await fetch("/data");   // this can sometimes take more than 100 ms
    const arr = data.arrayBuffer();    
     // update canvas with putImageData...

    console.log("finished processing", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of the **AbortControl** API which will help you in taking the latest api response. AbortController cancels the other APIs if multiple API hits are there and in that case, you will always be receiving the latest API response. This strategy is useful when you are polling the server in regular intervals. FETCH and Axios both provide access to AbortControler. Below I'm add a custom hook which I used in my project. I hope it will help you in understanding the concept.

It is built using Axios where I'm using ref as a reference to the previous call.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const AbortApiController = (url, page) => {

const cancelToken = useRef(null);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [reason, setReason] = useState('');
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const abortContol = async () => {
        if (cancelToken.current) {
            const str = 'cancled due to new request!';
            cancelToken.current.cancel(str);
        }
        setLoading(true);
        cancelToken.current = axios.CancelToken.source();
        try {
            let response = await axios.get(url, {
                cancelToken: cancelToken.current.token
            });
            setData(prev => [...prev, ...response.data]);
            setLoading(false);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            setReason(error.message);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
    abortContol();
}, [page]);

return { data, reason, loading };
}

export default AbortApiController;
```

Comment: Where does the OP say he's using React?

Comment: Thanks @ShashankSharma for your time, but indeed I don't use React, I just use simple JS.

Comment: @Basj this is a generic solution for the react framework. Meanwhile, I've mentioned that you can use AbortController WebApi to write it in native JS or in another framework. adding the link below for your reference. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController